# Python Selenium, get an element parent child element, based on another parent child element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I need some help, in the code below, I need to get the parent child element (<a), based on a condition (text) in the element <span. I've another rows that have the same structure, so I need to click in the <a with the condition based on the <span[image]

Comment: There's no `Detail` text right, it is `DETAIL` ?

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this XPath:

```py
//div[@class='inbox-row' and (.//span[contains(text(),'Detail')])]//a[contains(@class,'download-btn')]
```

or this

```py
//span[contains(text(),'Detail')]/../..//a[contains(@class,'download-btn')]
```

Possibly you will need to add a wait / delay before accessing this element. In this case you can use explicit wait as described by cruisepandey

Answer (score 0):

If the `span` has `DETAIL as a text`, then you give it a `try` with `below xpath` :

```
//span[contains(text(),'DETAIL')]/../following-sibling::div/descendant::a[contains(@class,'download')]
```

in code try it like :-

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'DETAIL')]/../following-sibling::div/descendant::a[contains(@class,'download')]").click()
```

or with **Explicit waits** :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'DETAIL')]/../following-sibling::div/descendant::a[contains(@class,'download')]"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

If the above two did not work, then try JS:-

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'DETAIL')]/../following-sibling::div/descendant::a[contains(@class,'download')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```